# How to Interpret Parameter Estimate Output from SPSS

Tags: probability, logistic, spss, multinomial-distribution, parameterization

[image]

Dear Community Members,

Given the outputs of the SPSS analysis, how can the exp (B ) and Beta values be interpreted in terms of odd ratio ? and in relation to how the independent variable affects the probability of outcome variables (choice of adaptation)?.

Thank you

George

Comment: Why not try https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/output/logistic-regression/ ?

Comment: I think this link can help you: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/spss/library/spss-libraryunderstanding-and-interpreting-parameter-estimates-in-regression-and-anova/

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exp+odds+ratio.